# About MQL5, how to close a trade and enter a trade

Tags: mql5

In the code below, I want to close all open buy trade before opening a sell in the place where I put plus sign.
I want to close all open sell trade before opening a buy in the place where I put asterisk sign.
Please, can anyone help me with the code? Thank you in advance for your help

```cpp
#include <Trade\Trade.mqh>
CTrade trade;

input double MyLotSize = 0.01;

void OnTick()
{
   double myMovingAverageArray1[],myMovingAverageArray2[];
   int movingAverageDefinition1 = iMA (_Symbol,_Period, 20,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE);
   int movingAverageDefinition2 = iMA (_Symbol,_Period, 50,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE);

   ArraySetAsSeries(myMovingAverageArray1,true);
   ArraySetAsSeries(myMovingAverageArray2,true);

   CopyBuffer(movingAverageDefinition1,0,0,3,myMovingAverageArray1);
   CopyBuffer(movingAverageDefinition2,0,0,3,myMovingAverageArray2);

   if((myMovingAverageArray1[0]>myMovingAverageArray2[0])&&(myMovingAverageArray1[1]<myMovingAverageArray2[1]))
   {
      double Ask=NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_ASK),_Digits);
      Comment ("BUY");

***********************************************************   
      trade.Buy(MyLotSize,NULL,Ask,0,(Ask+60 * _Point),NULL);
   }
   if((myMovingAverageArray1[0]<myMovingAverageArray2[0])&&(myMovingAverageArray1[1]>myMovingAverageArray2[1]))
   {
      double Bid=NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID),_Digits);
      Comment ("SELL");

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
      trade.Sell(MyLotSize,NULL,Bid,0,(Bid-60 * _Point),NULL);    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
void TryToClose(long type){
   if(!PositionSelect(_Symbol))return;
   if(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)!=type)return;
   trade.PositionClose(_Symbol);
}

add `TryToClose(POSITION_TYPE_BUY)` before opening a sell order.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. May God bless you

Comment: when i tested it in the backtest strategy for february 2019, it made a lot of profit. But when i try it for last year it ended up in huge loss, also when i tried it monthly for last year (i.e. selecting from january to december one by one and test it) it is showing loss..........please can you say to this occurence

Comment: What is the question? This is a programming forum, if you have questions about forex and trading - you might be better to ask at some forum about trading

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. when i tried the code you gave above, it still did not close the buy trade. please don't be annoyed.

Comment: How do you use this function? you need to compute the type that is contrary to the signal you have, e.g. if you have `POSITION_TYPE_BUY` signal, you need to close `POSITION_TYPE_SELL` first, right? and they are related between each other as `POSITION_TYPE_SELL=1-POSITION_TYPE_BUY` and vice versa.

Comment: #include <Trade\Trade.mqh>
CTrade trade;
string signal;
void OnTick()
   if (signal=="SELL" && PositionsTotal()<1)
      TryToClose(POSITION_TYPE_BUY);
      trade.Sell(0.10,NULL,Bid,0,0,NULL);
   if (signal=="BUY" && PositionsTotal()<1)
      TryToClose(POSITION_TYPE_SELL);
      trade.Buy(0.10,NULL,Ask,0,0,NULL);
  }
void TryToClose(long type){
   if(!PositionSelect(_Symbol))return;
   if(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)!=type)return;
   trade.PositionClose(_Symbol);   
},                                  This was how i did it, please help.

Comment: how do you think it should work? `if signal==Sell` and `PositionsTotal()<1` - `if PositionsTotal()<1` then you do not have any positions, right? and no need to close. otherwise PositionsTotal() is 1 or larger

Comment: i changed it to -  if(PositionsTotal()>1)......now it is no longer executing trade

Comment: If you don't mind, i can send the mq5 file to your email. i know am asking for too much......with humility i sincerely ask for your help

Comment: Of course not. if you have a job, find someone and hire at upwork. If you want to find a solution please post your code, net of other logic and identify the location you have problem with by debugging

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Constants for Key and IV
        byte[] key = { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xDC, 0xBA, 0x98, 0x76, 0x54, 0x32, 0x10 };
        byte[] iv = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF };

        // Path to the PDF file
        string filePath = "path/to/your/file.pdf";

        // Encrypt the PDF
        EncryptFile(filePath, key, iv);

        // Decrypt the encrypted PDF
        string encryptedFilePath = "path/to/your/encrypted/file.pdf";
        DecryptFile(encryptedFilePath, key, iv);

        Console.WriteLine("Encryption and decryption completed successfully!");
    }

    static void EncryptFile(string filePath, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = key;
            aesAlg.IV = iv;

            // Create a new file to write the encrypted data
            using (FileStream encryptedFile = File.Create("path/to/your/encrypted/file.pdf"))
            {
                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transformation
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create a CryptoStream to write the encrypted data to the file
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedFile, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    // Read the contents of the PDF file
                    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                    // Write the encrypted data to the CryptoStream
                    cryptoStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void DecryptFile(string filePath, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = key;
            aesAlg.IV = iv;

            // Create a new file to write the decrypted data
            using (FileStream decryptedFile = File.Create("path/to/your/decrypted/file.pdf"))
            {
                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transformation
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create a CryptoStream to read the encrypted data from the file
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(decryptedFile, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    // Read the contents of the encrypted file
                    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                    // Write the decrypted data to the CryptoStream
                    cryptoStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following: `if(PositionsTotal() < PositionsTotals)`. `PositionsTotal()` is a built in mql5 function, and `PositionsTotals` is a variable you can create and change, so it can be 1, etc. By using this logic, you can only have 1 trade open at a time.